# delayed_job process silently quits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, delayed-job

I wish I had more information to put here, but i'm kind of just casting out the nets and hoping someone has some ideas on what I can try or what direction to look. Basically I have a rails app that uses delayed jobs. It offloads a process that takes about 10 or 15 minutes to a background task. It was working fine up until yesterday. Now every time I log onto the server, I find that there are no delayed job processes running. I've restarted, stopped and started, etc. a dozen times and am getting nowhere. The second it tries to process the first item in the queue, the process gets killed, and nothing gets logged to the log file.

I tried running it like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run
```

Instead of the normal daemon:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

and that did not give me anymore info. Here is the output:

```
delayed_job: process with pid 4880 started.
Killed
```

It runs for probably 10 seconds before it just kills. I have no idea where to start on this. I've tried a number of things like downgrading daemon gem to 1.0.10 like suggested in other posts.

Any ideas would be amazing.

Comment: have you checked both `log/production.log` and `log/delayed_job.log` for errors? maybe just try booting it in 'normal' mode and see if errors are displayed in the terminal `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake jobs:work` - also I normally boot up the script with bundle as well, i.e. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job start`

Comment: also does the server have enough horse power to run your jobs? are you also using this machine to serve up web requests?

Comment: Hey, I believe you nailed it on the head with your second comment. I recently sized the box from a 2gb down to a 1gb. I'm load balancing between more smaller (1gb) nodes. I believe this one processes chews up all the ram and the OS kills it. I sized the box back up to 2gb and it now works! Looks like i've got to find a way to make the script more efficient. Its pulling about 3 million records and doing some number crunching on it. It only needs to do this maybe once a week though, so its hard to justify having such a large footprint box. Oh well, problem solved for now! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this in case anyone else comes across is, was that it was simply running out of memory and the OS was killing it.

I ran the jobs a couple times, and watched top while waiting. I saw the memory usage for that pid slowly climb till the process was killed and all memory released.

Hope that might help someone.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the worker is taking more memory and getting killed by OS. But is there a solution to this, because we cannot keep monitoring if the workers are dead or alive?

Comment: The solution for me was to increase memory on the server. Your options are to either increase memory on the server, or refactor your code to use less memory. Look for stuff that creates large in-memory arrays such as Model.all, or Collection.each. These can be changed to find_each for example to limit the number of records in memory at one time.